# Django tutorial. 404 on Generic Views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Update: Using Django 1.2.1 and Python 2.5.2 as offered by Dreamhost.

I'm having issues with the last part of the Django tutorial where the urls.py is changed to use generic views.  After I change the code I get 404's on the pages and even the index stops working.

I have gone over all of my templates to see if that was the issue but I removed any instance of poll and replaced it with object.  I have also attached the template for the index/object_list.

I am running this on Dreamhost and the static urls I set with views worked fine.

urls.py

```
from brsplash.models import Poll
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import *
admin.autodiscover()

info_dict = {
    'queryset': Poll.objects.all(),
}
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', info_dict),
    (r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail',     info_dict),
    url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/results/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', dict(info_dict,     template_name='brsplash/results.html'), 'poll_results'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'brsplash.views.vote'),
)    

urlpatterns += patterns('',
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

poll_list.html

```
    {% if object_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for object in object_list %}
        <li><a href="{{ object.id }}/">{{ object.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using class-based generic views? The old-style generic views in Django 1.3 are only there for compatibility with code built against earlier versions of Django. Of course, this is assuming you are in fact using Django 1.3, which if you're going through the tutorials, I'm not sure why you wouldn't be.

Comment: Sorry, Dreamhost only has Django 1.2.1 and Python 2.5.2 otherwise I would be using the newer 1.3 way.

Comment: watch out for the space in your regex after results/ `url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/results/    $',`  i doubt you mean to have that there and would 'prolly generate a 404

Comment: You can upgrade to Django 1.3 on Dreamhost: http://blog.oscarcp.com/?p=167

Comment: @jturnbull: Nice find. melkore: If you have any choice in the matter, you should use Django 1.3. It's never a good idea to begin a new project against an old codebase. Sooner or later you'll need to upgrade anyways, and it just makes it all that much more difficult. It more so if you're just beginning to learn Django. Working against 1.2.1 any new knowledge you gain is immediately outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can upgrade to Django 1.3 on Dreamhost: [blog.oscarcp.com/?p=167](http://blog.oscarcp.com/?p=167) –
>   jturnbull Sep 22 at 9:54

This fixed my issue with the urls.py issue I was having.  Once I upgraded to 1.3.1 and changed the code to reflect it, my pages came back.

Answer (score 4):

Django 1.3 introduced class-based generic views which will replace this function-based approach (see the note at the top of the [documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/)) so perhaps it's best to use them instead.

With the class-based approach, your new detail-page url would look something like this:

```
from brsplash.models import Poll
...
from django.views.generic import ListView

urlpatterns = {'',
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(model=Poll)),
    ...
}
```

This approach can be found in [part 4 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial04/#use-generic-views-less-code-is-better).

N.B.: I tend not to pass the `template_name` argument to `as_view` because, as stated in the docs:

> ListView generic view uses a default template called <app name>/<model name>_list.html

Comment: So I got a down-vote because you edited the question to say "1.2 only" after I posted the answer? :/